# Do Lev Parnas and Igor Fruman have anything to do with the Trump impeachment?

Tags: united-states, trump-impeachment

Lev Parnas and Igor Fruman are associates of Rudy Giuliani - Trump's personal lawyer. They have been charged with election finance violations - they had connections to a Russian Oligarch and sent money into the campaign of the president.

Does their being charged have any effect on the current impeachment trial going on with the president?

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/46555/19301

Comment: As this question is phrased it could a little opinion-based to answer, but nonetheless, one of the two associates apparently has made some claims of broader relevance https://www.vox.com/policy-and-politics/2019/11/23/20979143/giuliani-lev-parnas-devin-nunes-biden-investigation-impeachment-inquiry

Answer (score 5):

[Giuliani was *allegedly* tasked](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-11-06/trump-impeachment-defense-erodes-as-envoys-detail-giuliani-role) with coordinating and executing the *alleged* impeachable conduct on behalf of the President.

Lev Parnas and Igor Fruman *allegedly* [were directly involved](https://www.thedailybeast.com/lev-parnas-attended-rudy-giulianis-madrid-meeting-with-zelensky-aide-andriy-yermak) with Giuliani's Ukraine activities, which means they may be valuable fact witnesses. At the very least their testimony [relates to the firing of Marie Yovanovitch](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/justice-department/lutsenko-unnamed-ukrainian-who-led-plot-oust-yovanovitch-says-official-n1065246), which has previously been considered [relevant to the impeachment hearings](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/11/15/us/politics/marie-yovanovitch-testimony.html).

Additionally, they may have information that *allegedly* [implicates high Ranking Republicans](https://www.vox.com/policy-and-politics/2019/11/23/20979143/giuliani-lev-parnas-devin-nunes-biden-investigation-impeachment-inquiry) in the President's *alleged* impeachable conduct.

Them being charged provides leverage to convince them to testify, which may further support exisiting witness testimony and evidence in *removing the repeated use of the "alleged" label* in this answer, as well as lead to the discovery of even more witnesses and evidence.